# Bizarre fonts showing in .ppi when opened with notepad/notepad++

Tags: character-encoding, notepad++, special-characters, notepad, ppi

I've been looking for a solution for quite a while already, so I'm asking here.

I need to change a .ppi file to enable auto-update configuration of Sophos antivirus. The .ppi is iconfig.ppi, opening it with notepad and notepad++ shows bizarre characters, e.g.:

```
MZ       ÿÿ  ¸       @                                   8  º
´   Í!¸LÍ!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

Could you suggest a solution or point me to some source that I could read up myself? Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

This is binary file! Cannot edit it with N++. It's EXE one.

Comment: thank you. Do you know how I can edit then? Thanks in advance.